# What is the difference between template pattern and strategy pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

The two patterns (template and strategy) seem similar. The template method has an abstract base class with a skeletal method that drives the processing that needs to vary. The processing is done by calling abstract methods that are supplied by the concrete classes. We select the variation that we want by picking the concrete classes.

For example, we have a `Report` class, and an `HTMLReport` class that inherits from Report. Our `Report` class could look like this:

```
class Report
def initialize
@title = 'Monthly Report'
@text = ['Things are going', 'really really well']
end

def output_report
output_start
output_head
output_body_start
output_body
output_body_end
output_end
end


def output_body
@text.each do |line|
output_line(line)
end

def output_start
raise StandardError
end

def output_head
raise 'This needs to be implemented by the concrete class'
end
...
end
```

and our actual concrete class:

```
class HTMLReport < Report
def output_start
puts('<html>')
end

def output_head
puts('    <head>')
...
end

...
end
```

Actual use:

```
report = HTMLReport.new
report.output_report
```

The key thing is that the abstract class calls other methods for the variable parts of the algorithm, which we can then subclass (in this case through Ruby inheritance) and then work on the actual implementation.

However, some drawbacks (according to Russ Olsen):
- uses inheritance
- limits runtime flexibility... once we select a particular version of the algo, changing our mind is hard.

So, the strategy pattern:
- take out the annoyingly varying chunk of code and isolate it in its own class. Then create a whole family of classes, one for each variation.

Example:

```
class Formatter
def output_report(title, text)
raise 'Abstract Method called'
end
end

class HTMLFormatter < Formatter
def output_report(title, text)
puts('<html>')
puts('   <head>')
puts("   <title>#{title}</title>")
puts('    </head>')
...
end
```

Now our `Report` class looks like this:

```
class Report
attr_reader :title, :text
attr_accessor :formatter

def initialize(formatter)
@title = 'Monthly Report'
@text = ['Things are going', 'really, really well.']
@formatter = formatter
end

def output_report
@formatter.output_report(@title, @text)
end
end
```

So, correct me if I'm wrong, it looks like since the strategies all have the same interface, we can just delegate to them in the `Report` class. The `Report` class is called the `context` by those GOF people.

but how does this allow us to switch strategies at runtime? We still call them like this right?

```
report = Report.new(HTMLFormatter.new)
report.output_report
```

What are the main differences?

Comment: If you want to change the formatting in the template method version, you have to create an entirely new report (because you need a different subclass). In the strategy version, you can just assign a new formatter to the existing report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template pattern isn't much of a pattern.  It simply describes what we all know to be the fundamentals of polymorphism.  The Strategy Pattern on the other hand defines a common interface for "functions"/"strategies" which can be swapped out at run time.  Here's an example of the Strategy Pattern in Java (sorry, not well versed in Ruby):

Disclaimer: Not my code, great example.

```
public interface Strategy {
   public int doOperation(int num1, int num2);
}

public class OperationAdd implements Strategy{
   @Override
   public int doOperation(int num1, int num2) {
     return num1 + num2;
   }
}

public class OperationSubstract implements Strategy{
   @Override
   public int doOperation(int num1, int num2) {
      return num1 - num2;
   }
}

// Using this Context and common Strategy interface, we can utilize any operation
// we want.
public class Context {
   private Strategy strategy;

   public Context(Strategy strategy){
       this.strategy = strategy;
   }

   public int executeStrategy(int num1, int num2){
      return strategy.doOperation(num1, num2);
   }
}

public class StrategyPatternDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       // Implement any Operation that implements Strategy interface
       Context context = new Context(new OperationAdd());       
       System.out.println("10 + 5 = " + context.executeStrategy(10, 5));

       context = new Context(new OperationSubstract());     
       System.out.println("10 - 5 = " + context.executeStrategy(10, 5));

       context = new Context(new OperationMultiply());      
       System.out.println("10 * 5 = " + context.executeStrategy(10, 5));
   }
}
```

Comment: Im not too well versed in Java, mind taking me through this a bit?

Comment: Sure, I just started learning Ruby this week so not too sure how to do this in Ruby but I'm sure it can be done.  Create Classes "Add", "Subtract" which inherit from a base class called "Strategy" and do their work in a method called `doOperation`.  Create another class called "Context" with a method called `execute`.  Within this `execute` method, "Context" will call this `doOperation` method.  When Context is created, it will be created with the type of Operation to be performed ex: `Context.new( new Add )` - if that's even valid Ruby.

Comment: Or I meant, mind just talking me through your Java? Mine is rusty... what is this again: ` main(String[] args)` and `private Strategy strategy` and `public int doOperation(int num1, int num2) {
      return num1 - num2;
   }`?

Comment: I kind of just did.  The entire application starts at `main(String[] args)`.  It creates a `new Context` object passing in a `new OperationAdd` object.  Since `OperationAdd` inherits from `Strategy` and implements `doOperation`, if you look at the `Context` class, all it has to do is call the instance variable `strategy.doOperation(num1, num2)`.  This is because it is guaranteed that all `Strategy`'s implement this interface.